# Delete a sheet where name starts with a certain value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete a sheet where the name starts with "data as at". I've used the following but not working.

```
For Each SheetExists In Worksheets
    If Left(SheetExists.Name, 10) = "Data as at" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(Left("Data as at", 10)).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next SheetExists
```

It comes back with a subscript error for the following line.

```
Sheets(Left("Data as at", 10)).Delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>`Sheets(Left("Data as at", 10)).Delete`</s>

`SheetExists.Delete`